# adblock от google chrome блокирует css файл

Tags: css, google-chrome

Создавал сайт, во всех браузерах верстка нормальная. 
Хром блокирует css файл. Когда  отключаю Адблок - сайт работает. 
Как это лечить?

Comment: переименовать css файл или путь к нему ? если не ваш сайт, то сделать исключение

Comment: Сайт мой. Переименование не спасает.

Comment: Как я понял, проблема была в названии сайта. На localhost он назывался advert. Переименовал сайт, сейчас грузит нормально. Но что делать, если я хочу испльзовать это доменное имя в просторах web?

Comment: если ваш сайт называется advert, то он связан с рекламой видимо, адблок блокирует рекламу, в чем проблема непонятно.

Comment: сайт связан с объявлениями.

Comment: Ну вот, а пользователи adblock'а не любят читать объявления. :) Доменное имя, содержащее advert -- плохая идея, я бы на такой сайт не пошёл. Если вы очень-очень хотите его сохранить, напишите разработчикам AdBlockPlus и убедите их, что ваш сайт не рекламный. Но я бы всё же поменял домен.